# General theory of left-exact localization?

Tags: ct.category-theory

A left-exact localization of a category is a reflective subcategory such that the reflector preserves finite limits.  There are several prominent examples of such localizations, such as sheafification, and localization of module categories.  Is there a general theory of such localizations?

I don't have any particular type of result in mind, but given the prominence of the two examples I mentioned, it seems like the topic of left-exact localizations must have been studied for its own sake.

Comment: Special cases of reflective localisation in locally presentable categories are studied in § 1.C of [Adámek and Rosický, _Locally presentable and accessible categories_] and, of course, the theory of left exact localisations of presheaf toposes is just the theory of Grothendieck topologies. 

Comment: Basics of the general theory are reviewed in the first thirteen pages of arXiv:0806.1324 Localization theory for triangulated categories. 

Comment: I don't see where Krause addresses left-exactness.

Comment: The first volume of Borceux's "Handbook of categorical algebra" has some discussion of left exact localizations.

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo, that does help.  (The terminology is slightly different than I used above, so if anyone is curious it's section 5.6.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is already answered in the comments

Comment: @DavidWhite Questions are off-topic now if they have answers?  A surprising development for MO.

Comment: Or you could take the answer from the comments and make it a CW answer to your question. The point is to prevent the question from automatically being bumped to the front-page by the software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to tie this one up, the cited result in Borceux (Prop 5.6.1) says the following:

**Proposition:** Let $\mathcal C$ be a finitely-complete category and let $L \mathcal C$ be a reflective subcategory. Let $\mathcal W$ be the class of morphisms inverted by the reflector $r: \mathcal C \to L\mathcal C$. Then $r$ is left exact if and only if $\mathcal W$ is stable under base change.

This continues to hold in the $\infty$-categorical context. Here is a proof adapted from Borceux which works $\infty$-categorically.

**Proof:** The "only if" direction is clear; we prove "if". First, since $i$ preserves terminal objects we have that the terminal object of $L\mathcal C$ is the terminal object of $\mathcal C$ and in particular is $\mathcal W$-local, so $L$ preserves terminal objects.

So it will suffice to show that $L$ preserves pullbacks. To this end, it is sufficient to show that if we have a natural transformation from the pullback square on the left to the one on the right below, and if the components $B \xrightarrow \sim B'$, $C \xrightarrow \sim C'$, and $D \xrightarrow \sim D'$ are all in $\mathcal W$, then so is the map $A \to A'$.

$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} A @>>> B\\ @VVV  @VVV\\ C @>>> D \end{CD} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad\begin{CD} A' @>>> B'\\ @VVV  @VVV\\ C' @>>> D' \end{CD}$

By pullback-stability and 2/3, the map $B \times_{D'} C \xrightarrow \sim A'$ is in $\mathcal W$. So by 2/3 it will suffice to show that the map $A \to B \times_{D'} C$ is in $\mathcal W$. By pullback-stability and 2/3, the map $D \xrightarrow \sim D \times_{D'} D$ is in $\mathcal W$, so it will suffice by pullback-stability to show that the following two squares are pullbacks:

$\begin{CD} A @>>> B @>>> D \\ @VVV  @VVV @VV^\sim V \\
B \times_{D'} C @>>> B \times_{D'} D @>>> D \times_{D'} D \end{CD}$

This can be seen using the following two diagrams:

$\begin{CD} A @>>> B \\ @VVV  @VVV \\
B \times_{D'} C @>>> B \times_{D'} D @>>> B \\ @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
C @>>> D @>>> D' \end{CD}
\quad \begin{CD} B @>>> D \\ @VVV  @VVV \\
B \times_{D'} D @>>> D \times_{D'} D @>>> D \\ @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
B @>>> D @>>> D' \end{CD}
$

In each case we argue that the bottom-right square and the composite of the lower two squares is a pullback, so the bottom-left square is a pullback. Since the composite of the left two squares is also a pullback, it results that the top-left square is a pullback.

Comment: Coming back to this, it took me awhile to recall that $B \times_{D'} C \to B' \times_{D'} C \to B' \times_{D'} C' = A'$ is the composite of a base-change of $B \overset \sim \to B'$ and a base-change of $C \overset \sim \to C'$, which is why it's in $\mathcal L$ (as claimed in the first line after the first display).

Answer (score 7):

This is my bibliography on the subject. Indeed Bourceux was quite relevant in this topic.

> - *Borceux*, **Sheaves of algebras for a commutative theory**, Ann. Soc. Sci. Bruxelles Sér. I 95 (1981), no. 1, 3–19
> - *Borceux and Kelly*, **On locales of localizations**, J. Pure Appl. Algebra, Volume 46, Issue 1, 1987, Pages 1-34.
> - *Borceux and Veit*, **On the Left Exactness of Orthogonal Reflections**
>   J. Pure Appl. Algebra, 49 (1987), pp. 33-42.
> - *Borceux*, **Subobject Classifier for Algebraic Structures**.
>   J. Algebra, 112 (1988), pp. 306-314.
> - *Veit*, **Sheaves, localizations, and unstable extensions: Some counterexamples**. J. Pure Appl. Algebra, Volume 140, Issue 2, July 1991, Pages 370-391.
> - *Borceux and Quinteiro*. **A theory of enriched sheaves**. Cahiers de Topologie et Géométrie Différentielle Catégoriques 37.2 (1996): 145-162.
> - *Garner and Lack*, **Lex Colimits**. J. Pure Appl. Algebra. Volume 216, Issue 6, June 2012, Pages 1372-1396.

Comment: I think <<Cassidy, C.; Hébert, M.; Kelly, G. M. Reflective subcategories, localizations and factorization systems. *J. Austral. Math. Soc. Ser. A* **38** (1985), no. 3, 287--329.>> also belongs on this list.