# Is there something similar to Lawvere-Tierney topologies for Abelian categories?

Tags: topos-theory, abelian-categories, grothendieck-topology, sites

Lawvere-Tierney topologies generalize the notion of local operators on a Topos from Sheaf toposes over a Grothendieck site to arbitrary Toposes.

However, while the special case of Sheaves of sets or Sheaves of spaces in a topos is one of the most common cases, Sheaves of modules over a ring R or more generally sheaves of algebraic objects in an Abelian category are also a very important case.

Now, Abelian categories [are in some ways very similar to toposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/AT+category) with a slightly different behaviour of the initial and final objects. Is there a concept similar to the LT topology that generalizes the notion of "locally" from abelian categories of sheaves on a site to general abelian categories without explicitly referring to their construction?

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to give much more than a cursory reply, but a good search term might be "torsion theory". The nLab article https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsion+theory has some material and references to get you started.

Comment: More search terms: Gabriel topology on an abelian category, universal closure operator.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128446/general-theory-of-left-exact-localization/349948#349948

Comment: @saolof In a sense, no, because there is no subobject classifier nor anything analogous that "makes representable" the notion of locality. But you don't need a representing object to study left exact localisations.